# Loading LKM via QEMU

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, qemu

I run Linux kernel image on QEMU, now I need to load dynamic module in the kernel running in QEMU.

I have no clue how to do that, could you please advice or provide appropriate reference.

Comment: Not sure whats the problem in loading? There is no difference in loading module on host or vm.

Comment: I successfully create and compile the module, now how to transfer it to the guest OS (i.e. my compiled kernel) running on QEMU.

Comment: You don't have disk or network interface attacted to interface

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images

Comment: QEMU interface card? In my system QEMU runs on Ubuntu that too runs on Oracle VM. That runs on a windows machine..

Comment: It's not about interface card. Look for Qemu networking and/or attaching disk Image. The way I do I create Qemu Image and create filesystem on the disk image and pass it as an argument to qemu. http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking and en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images.

Comment: So, you add the file into the filesystem, when you are creating it..correct?

Comment: Yes i mount the fs and copy  or do a scp